# Having problems selecting items from mySQL database

Tags: mysql

Tables:

```
User:
ID
gender
looking_for_gender

User_Status:
User_ID1
User_ID2
Status
```

While this select works, I also want to select users that has no status. In other words I want to select everyone that has no status or != FRIENDS. Somehow `AND` & `OR` does not do the trick.

Currently working query:

```
SELECT u.* FROM User u
JOIN User_Status us ON u.ID = us.User_ID1
WHERE us.Status != "FRIENDS"
AND us.User_ID2 =4 AND gender ="f"
```

Sample Data User_Status:
User_ID1 ----- User_ID2 ----- Status
---- 1 ---------------- 4 ------------ has_send_request
---- 2 ---------------- 4 ------------ friends
---- 3 ---------------- 4 ------------ friends

Sample Data User:
ID
0
1
2
3
4
5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add the condition "has no Status" with `or`

```
WHERE (us.Status != "FRIENDS" or us.status is null) AND us.User_ID2 =4 AND gender ="f"
```

UPDATE after clarification:

```
select u.* from user u left join user_status us on u.id = User_ID1 and us.User_ID2 =4  where gender ="f" and (us.Status != "FRIENDS" or us.status is null)
```

Comment: What means `not seem to work`? Some more Details please

Comment: @VeraPerrone and sample data are great

Comment: @Jean Let me explain, I have 2 status right now, has_send_invite and friends. I want to select everyone that has no status and everyone that does not have the status of friends. Right now I only get the people that has the status of has_send_invite, but not the people that has no status at all.

Comment: @VeraPerrone No Status means no entry in User_status?

Comment: yes, I have added some example data. In the example above user 1 is selected but not user 0 or 5

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are finding the NOT clause:

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/not.php

You can make something like:

```
 SELECT u.* FROM User u JOIN User_Status us ON u.ID = us.User_ID1 WHERE status IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

when you evaluate null u need to use is null, otherwise it will always return false.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM User u
INNER JOIN User_Status us
    ON u.ID = us.User_ID1
WHERE (us.STATUS != "FRIENDS" OR us.STATUS IS NULL) 
    AND us.User_ID2 = 4
    AND gender = "f"
```